# Свойство connectionstring не инициализированно SqlCommandBuilder

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview

Пытаюсь обновить базу данных через адаптер но выскакивает - сообщение что Свойство connectionstring не инициализированно.

```
public static string connectionString = @"Data Source=(local)\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Clothing_DB;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=15;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=True;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False";


public void setNewSizes()
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        conn.Open();
        try
        {
            adapterSize.UpdateCommand = cmdBuilder.GetUpdateCommand();
            adapterSize.Update(recivedData.Tables[0]);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, ex.Source);
        }
    }
}
```

adapterSize это обьект SqlDataAdapter, cmdBuilder - SqlCommandBuilder.
вот код адаптера и метода который получает DataSet из базы

```
static string querySelect = "select * from [customers_Sizes] where ID_customers = @ID";
private  DataSet recivedData;
static public SqlDataAdapter adapterSize = new SqlDataAdapter(querySelect, connectionString);
SqlCommandBuilder cmdBuilder;
public DataTable clientSizes(int ID)
{
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand commSelect = new SqlCommand(querySelect, conn);
        commSelect.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", ID);
        adapterSize = new SqlDataAdapter(commSelect);
        cmdBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(adapterSize);
        recivedData = new DataSet();
        adapterSize.Fill(recivedData);
        table = recivedData.Tables[0];
        conn.Close();
    }
    return table;
}
```

что ему не нравится?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59777/discussion-on-question-by---connectionstring--).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По итогам обсуждения в комментариях и чате.

`SqlCommandBuilder.GetUpdateCommand()` предназначен для получения автоматически сформированного объекта типа `SqlCommand`, но для формирования этого объекта необходимы дополнительные условия:

- автоматическая генерация допустима только для простых, одно-табличных запросов.
- должен быть корректно настроен мапинг таблицы, за это в принципе отвечает адаптер.
- необходимо указать имя таблицы, с которой работает адаптер.
- необходимо установить свойство `SqlDataAdapter.SelectCommand`

Если эти условия не выполнены, `SqlCommandBuilder.GetUpdateCommand()` отработает некорректно и `ConnectionString` окажется крайним, т.к. проверяется на наличие и корректность первым.

Пример корректного использования связки адаптера с билдером приведен в MSDN:

```
public static DataSet SelectSqlRows(string connectionString,
    string queryString, string tableName)
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
        adapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
        SqlCommandBuilder builder = new SqlCommandBuilder(adapter);

        connection.Open();

        DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
        adapter.Fill(dataSet, tableName);

        //code to modify data in DataSet here

        builder.GetUpdateCommand();

        //Without the SqlCommandBuilder this line would fail
        adapter.Update(dataSet, tableName);

        return dataSet;
    }
}
```

Также полезно: [Создание команд с помощью объекта CommandBuilders](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/tf579hcz(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: А если мы не используем SqlCommandBuilder вообще то и обьект SqlCommand не используется ? Или просто иначе?

Comment: он используется, но внутри адаптера. Его можно заменить при необходимости, или поправить таймауты выполнения например

Comment: Вообще классы ADO.NET являются только оболочками над SQL-командами также, как например List - умная оболочка над Array. Они не избавляют от необходимости писать SQL-код

Comment: Простите, не понял А SqlCommandBuilder от чего избавляет? Он использует адаптер в котором уже прописан sql код и без него можно спокойно обойтись.  Выглядит как лишний код.

Comment: И SqlCommand вовсе не автоматически формируется.

Comment: @Сергей SqlCommandBuilder если верить документации, (вы кстати пробовали использовать пример из описания этого класса?) может генерировать команды, но только для однотабличных простых селектов, и ему нужно знать имя таблицы, чтобы составить запрос, вроде как то так. Но тут лучше попробовать, потому что на MSDN как-то жиденько это описано.

Comment: Сам пример не пробовал, но у меня сегодня как раз и был тот случай когда я хотел получить от него команду. И выбрал из dataset только одну таблицу.

Comment: При вызове SqlDataAdapter.Update(...), адаптер обращается к команде, ... Адаптер обращается к команде адаптера, получается так.

Comment: @Сергей обновил ответ